# How can I solve the problem with redirecting 302 to 200, probably the reason is from the JS themselves?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use a form that posts comments. It is short with the fields Name, Mail and Comment. However, when the site is open, through another language, for example from German, it is opened in English website.com - Duith version, website.com/en/ - english version. I get a problem and the form gives an error: "An error occurred while processing the form"

Once I debugged it turned out that there was some "redirect" from 302 to 200, how can I solve the problem with this redirection and not get this problem anymore?

POST - https://website.com/?do=comments
Status - 302 Found

GET - https://website.com/en/?do=comments
Status - 200 OK

This is my HTML

```
        <form action="/?do=comments" method="post" id="f5feafacf21681" class="b-comment_form" data-ajax="true">
            <div class="form-group form-group-25">
                <div class="form">
                    <label class="required">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" required autocomplete="name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form">
                    <label class="required">E-mail:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required autocomplete="email" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form">
                <textarea name="text" rows="5" placeholder="Comment" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
                <input type="hidden" name="module" value="news" />
                <input type="hidden" name="module_id" value="10707" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is my JS

```
// Class for submitting forms
var Form = function() {
    this.init();
};
Form.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        var _this = this;

        $(document).on('submit', 'form[data-ajax]', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ( ! $(this).hasClass('form-loading') ) {
                _this.submit( $(this).attr('id') );
            }
        });
    },
    submit: function(form_id, callback) {
        if ( ! form_id ) form_id = 'form';
        var form = $('#' + form_id), url = form.attr('action'), btn = form.find('*[type="submit"]');
        
        if ( form.attr('enctype') == 'multipart/form-data' ) {
            var str = new FormData(form[0]),
                multipart = true;
            str.append('form_id', form_id);
            str.append('utm_url', this_url);
            str.append('utm_title', this_title);
        } else {
            var str = form.serialize() + '&form_id=' + form_id + '&utm_url=' + this_url + '&utm_title=' + this_title,
                multipart = false;
        }
        
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: str,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: ( multipart ) ? false : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            processData: ( multipart ) ? false : true,
            beforeSend: function() {
                form.addClass('form-loading');
                btn.addClass('process');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if ( data == 'error' ) return false;

                if ( callback && typeof(callback) === "function" ) {
                    callback(form_id, data);
                } else {
                    if ( data.answer == 'stop' ) {
                        error( data.error );
                    } else {
                        if ( data.success ) success( data.success );
                    }
                    if ( data.eval ) eval( data.eval );
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                error( 'An error occurred while processing the form' );
            },
            complete: function() {
                form.removeClass('form-loading');
                btn.removeClass('process');
                if ( form.find('#captcha') ) reload();
            }
        });
    }
}, $(document).ready(function() {
    Form = new Form
});
```

Comment: POST - https://website.com/?do=comments Status - 302 Found

this shouldn't be post format " ? " ,

Comment: @SikanderNawaz Didn't understand your question? If I use the default language, which is located in the root directory site.com/ - the code works. But if I use another language that is in "under directory" site.com/en, the code breaks.